# CSS aliases: marginTop vs margin-top?

Tags: css

I had initially noticed both of these work when using the jQuery css method and thought it had something to do with jQuery, but then I realized both of them were (apparently) valid aliases for the same CSS property anyway.

What's with that? I can't find it documented ANYWHERE. Every site just mentions one or the other and nobody discusses that it has two names.

I haven't tested it, but I would assume it works the same way for the other three margins. And this opens up the possibility that many different CSS properties have aliases. Is this true, and if so, is there any sort of reference for what the various aliases might be?

Note: when using 'margin-top' with jQuery, it has to be formatted as a string and not as a symbol because of the hyphen, a.k.a. just use quotes around it.

Comment: There's no aliases in CSS. CSS properties are written in *camelCase* format in JavaScript to be used as a property.

Comment: jQuery just delegates to each element’s `style` property. `style` uses all camelCase properties, because `el.style["margin-top"]` doesn’t look good. jQuery automatically does the conversion for you from `foo-bar` to `fooBar` (plus vendor prefixes as appropriate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the jQUery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

> Also, jQuery can equally interpret the CSS and DOM formatting of multiple-word properties. For example, jQuery understands and returns the correct value for both .css( "background-color" ) and .css( "backgroundColor" ).

`margin-top` is the CSS syntax, `marginTop` is the DOM syntax.

Comment: Just an addendum: Javascript doesn't allow hyphens in variables, so `style.margin-top` is invalid. Javascript has to refer to it as `marginTop`

Comment: It doesn't _have_ to, it could have been done as `style["margin-top"]`. But that's clearly the motivation for the difference.